Initial patch install checking via SCCM query
I want to make a better query for Windows Server OS patching (2016 & 2019).  The one listed below is what I wrote that my company currently uses.  If a newly built servers OS install time is between 4 and 72 hours old that server is added to the Auto Install Patches Asset Collection to get auto patched to current.  Most of the time it works but we have had a few locations with really bad network connections not get new servers patched within the queries timeframe.  I would prefer to not extend the timeframe but instead make a smarter query.
Current Query:
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
from SMS_R_System     
inner join SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId    
where     
( DATEDIFF(HH, SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.InstallDate, GetDate()) <= 72 and DATEDIFF(HH, SMS_G_System_OPERATING_SYSTEM.InstallDate, GetDate()) >= 4)

As the OS image that is used to install new servers have older baked in patches, is there a way to have a query check the latest installed patch date against the OS install date?  If any patch is found to be installed after the install date then the latest patch set has been installed and the server can be dropped from the Auto Install Asset Collection.  I only need the current patches installed as a deployment team schedules any future released patches as needed.
I found a script that looks like it could be incoporated into what I currently have but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.  The script is located here:  https://bestitsm.wordpress.com/2018/07/12/how-to-get-list-of-installed-hotfixes-from-sccm-database/

One area for improvement is using DATEADD() on GetDate() by itself, then comparing the result to the InstallDate column. This will work better with indexes.

Also, I looked, and my SCCM system does not have those tables. It has several with similar/related names, but not those.

One final note: while Stack Overflow has a lot of people who are highly skilled with SQL, there are relatively few here who know anything at all about SCCM... and as such you might do a lot better asking over at ServerFault.com

I cannot really confirm that there is great support for sccm questions on serverfault, however one thing to point out here. A query for a collection in SCCM is not SQL at all it is Extended WQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/core/understand/extended-wmi-query-language) so very limited in its possibilities
